I am getting a ValueError when trying to check if two lists are the same, why is this and how can I fix this
I am using pickle to save something to a file, and am trying to check if the thing loaded back in is the exact same as the thing that was saved to the file, for later in the program and am receiving the error message:
  File "(Directory blurred for privacy)", line 28, in <module>
    if newvalues == myvalues:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

when I try to check if they are equal to each other. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried iterating through them both and checking if each element is the same, and if any element is different, then it tells me, but this also returns the same error. I am using python 3.10 in Pycharm. The outputs from print(type(myvalues)) and print(type(newvalues)) are both the same thing, which is <class 'list'>
my code is here:
print ("start")
import mnist_loader
training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()

import network
net = network.Network([784, 30, 10]) # amount of neurons in each layer is the numbers

net.SGD(training_data, 2, 10, 3.0, test_data = test_data)

myvalues = net.getWeightsAndBiases()


# Saving it - not part of the code from book
print("\n \n \n")
with open("data.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(myvalues, file)

with open("data.pickle", "rb") as file:
    newvalues = pickle.load(file)

print(newvalues)

print("myvalues is:", type(myvalues))
print("newvalues is:", type(newvalues))
if newvalues == myvalues:
    print("working")

the imports come from this github repo: https://github.com/unexploredtest/neural-networks-and-deep-learning with an addition to the Network class in the network file of:
def getWeightsAndBiases(self):
    weightsandbiases = [self.weights, self.biases]
    print(weightsandbiases)
    return weightsandbiases

I tried to see if this error was encountered before, and found this question: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). I tried what was suggested on there, but it didn't solve the problem.
here are the values stored:
myvalues:
[[array([[ 0.49047849, -0.49061768,  1.38129925, ...,  1.38365421,
        -2.84816588,  1.33435502],
       [ 0.14265502, -0.40701424, -0.06344381, ..., -0.04221331,
         1.87971909,  0.16228496],
       [ 1.25865165,  0.5694624 , -0.15033885, ..., -0.33268354,
         1.82849422, -0.32053569],
       ...,
       [-0.86875935, -1.31803218, -0.06188464, ...,  0.80358709,
        -1.22506318,  0.65488229],
       [ 0.72230337,  1.20813743,  0.70311973, ..., -1.31394859,
        -1.58026529,  1.573237  ],
       [ 0.75231614,  1.82261382,  0.28055294, ...,  0.63589566,
         1.54549887, -0.09006421]]), array([[ 9.04625312e-01, -1.20168740e+00, -2.05344286e+00,
         9.95282006e-01, -2.61128392e-01,  2.46883716e+00,
        -1.26605928e+00, -2.87461934e-01, -2.55345158e+00,
         3.95568507e+00,  6.47950996e-01,  2.92748875e-01,
        -1.90249337e+00, -2.05367861e+00,  1.17277862e+00,
         1.57364635e-01, -2.35467086e+00, -2.06776136e+00,
        -8.59204716e-02, -2.26256190e-01, -1.03518297e+00,
        -2.54459855e+00, -1.89909493e+00, -1.99529114e+00,
        -1.89778623e+00, -1.74062008e+00,  1.33135961e+00,
         1.66467987e-01,  3.65705086e-01,  1.15453112e+00],
       [ 5.18282670e-01,  2.10463982e+00,  2.22985297e-01,
         9.32875441e-02,  7.28948913e-01, -1.10041794e+00,
        -1.98894338e+00,  1.77096789e+00,  2.94633320e+00,
        -1.42998907e+00, -1.45059944e+00,  1.33818451e+00,
         2.37342106e+00, -2.77977954e+00, -2.89356946e+00,
         3.48555860e-01, -1.47593219e+00, -7.17198708e-01,
        -2.04548364e+00, -1.60860270e-02,  2.28442674e+00,
        -2.13940877e+00, -2.34960215e+00,  1.45710833e+00,
        -2.06243860e-02,  3.60329517e-01, -1.54618740e+00,
         2.19487096e+00, -1.04334123e-01, -2.94963266e+00],
       [-1.25268187e+00,  1.03468220e+00, -2.09360677e+00,
         2.72615924e+00,  8.03204286e-01, -1.21663915e+00,
        -3.14265961e+00, -2.99772834e-01, -6.55293117e-01,
        -1.85560311e+00, -1.69062463e-01,  1.53853932e-01,
         2.25068573e+00,  1.95227101e+00,  1.51207030e+00,
        -1.92508002e+00, -2.74164612e+00, -2.93852455e+00,
         2.01606172e+00, -6.91112599e-02, -2.27444607e+00,
        -2.75360145e+00, -1.62466484e-01,  1.68692850e+00,
         5.08041338e-01,  1.62613626e+00, -5.29857957e-02,
        -1.65836590e+00, -1.29237245e-03,  1.42649470e+00],
       [-1.00819993e+00,  2.63043465e+00, -8.48382777e-02,
        -4.38687260e-01,  3.76851240e-02,  5.60457581e-01,
        -1.86550332e+00, -4.34641085e-01, -3.02091630e+00,
        -1.55467958e+00,  7.91021890e-01,  1.23804246e+00,
         8.97229505e-01,  4.29841772e-01, -2.42525138e+00,
        -1.50064714e+00, -1.63826402e+00,  3.17469593e+00,
        -3.22054928e+00,  1.28392045e-01, -2.31741089e+00,
        -2.01552447e+00, -9.76992399e-01, -2.11558724e+00,
         1.92055199e+00,  5.55657968e-02, -1.75658363e+00,
        -2.46376324e+00,  1.73383489e+00,  1.56852876e+00],
       [-2.69408613e+00, -1.65159886e-01,  1.14444474e+00,
         1.23856668e+00,  1.02779879e+00,  2.81014023e+00,
         1.94193324e+00,  4.19896377e+00,  4.76766390e-01,
        -1.59098892e+00, -3.46217943e+00, -8.54517359e-01,
        -3.45234416e+00,  6.83242926e-01,  3.85724030e-02,
        -1.52278124e+00, -3.58015741e+00, -1.08273825e+00,
        -8.58495236e-02, -9.03825817e-01,  6.78730044e-01,
         5.18992143e-01,  3.42742226e+00, -1.52145368e+00,
         4.42189117e-01, -3.51066960e-01,  3.23080044e-01,
        -1.57079554e+00,  1.56477334e+00,  6.25506107e-01],
       [-3.33084155e-01, -2.79916035e+00,  5.22989199e-01,
         1.38178594e+00,  3.46671869e-01, -2.52869916e+00,
        -2.85003881e+00,  3.28334995e-01, -2.84497518e+00,
        -3.13336002e+00,  1.80758606e+00, -2.91602798e-01,
        -1.37399163e+00,  9.64047229e-01, -1.64202622e+00,
        -1.16234051e+00, -9.29535117e-01,  1.41014006e+00,
        -2.46834534e-01, -2.55373025e+00,  3.09016395e+00,
         1.98639570e+00,  1.10538587e+00,  4.80455892e-01,
        -1.63467864e+00,  7.28759567e-01,  2.64827251e+00,
         4.19659350e+00,  1.74234240e+00, -1.03982207e+00],
       [-1.99266677e+00, -3.45359895e+00, -1.66118838e+00,
        -6.86597421e-01, -3.64325347e-01,  2.37331770e+00,
         2.69295889e+00, -1.47113808e+00,  1.39082250e+00,
        -1.46233207e+00,  1.33042898e+00, -2.33113544e+00,
        -1.69593344e+00, -1.08305993e+00,  1.47304532e+00,
        -8.01031798e-01, -1.39920442e-01, -3.70400598e-01,
        -6.01091586e-01, -2.16153982e+00,  9.10587323e-01,
        -1.50354389e+00, -2.94728783e+00,  1.89153136e+00,
         1.43422568e+00, -6.14883762e-01, -1.29433499e+00,
         3.50730738e-01,  4.83855845e-03, -1.75349388e+00],
       [-1.65761588e+00, -5.63733247e-01,  4.25340960e-01,
         2.12352772e+00,  5.11942027e-01,  2.34213260e-01,
        -1.07488277e+00, -1.74688310e-01,  2.17174402e-02,
         2.48123976e-02, -3.62391678e-01,  6.56484593e-01,
         7.67530180e-01, -2.79774226e+00, -1.52769623e-01,
        -1.34026002e+00, -7.56261158e-01, -4.26031821e-01,
        -4.15734416e-01, -5.99522808e-01, -1.37719915e+00,
        -7.67536696e-01,  2.65846043e-01,  1.55756415e-01,
         6.99817419e-02,  5.52418194e-01, -3.16887735e+00,
         6.30433024e-01, -1.71636457e+00, -8.35886404e-01],
       [ 3.21696401e-01, -1.71443017e+00,  3.76632012e+00,
        -1.83856335e+00,  1.47475018e+00,  1.59866379e+00,
        -2.73854827e+00, -7.24335260e-02,  2.65913111e+00,
        -1.57314023e+00,  2.53103461e+00, -1.66971607e+00,
         9.40072925e-01,  9.69474126e-01, -1.69713625e+00,
        -9.04140008e-01, -2.44440263e+00, -5.97944024e-01,
         2.19066743e+00, -2.55224131e+00, -2.42208274e+00,
        -1.39494323e+00, -2.75270420e+00, -2.01258784e+00,
        -1.65333206e+00,  2.14839247e-01,  5.38008934e-01,
        -4.48039975e+00,  1.68560318e+00, -1.21934927e+00],
       [ 3.06599211e+00, -7.07372169e-01, -6.88577595e-01,
         6.59071311e-01, -2.00414045e+00,  4.02737209e+00,
         3.42991453e+00, -4.16059766e+00,  7.54238608e-03,
        -1.29674288e+00, -1.39663044e+00, -9.85410716e-01,
         3.45266027e+00,  1.56376928e-02,  5.27424947e-01,
        -2.58017367e+00, -2.34544641e+00,  8.51448321e-01,
        -6.64417574e-02, -3.17204624e+00, -1.60448330e+00,
         4.87718256e-01,  2.03572175e+00, -1.87365026e+00,
         3.12554540e-01, -1.03559520e+00,  2.60828651e-01,
        -1.13135153e+00,  1.25463236e+00, -1.43925684e+00]])], [array([[ 0.94832068],
       [-0.06266606],
       [-1.7593827 ],
       [-0.53870002],
       [-1.55386951],
       [-1.11558379],
       [ 0.02919313],
       [-0.28376287],
       [-0.54389668],
       [-2.50103053],
       [-0.08829055],
       [ 0.40428512],
       [-1.320014  ],
       [-0.59260049],
       [-0.77699536],
       [ 0.30419453],
       [ 0.33959821],
       [ 0.18065646],
       [ 0.55219802],
       [-0.02601865],
       [-0.01003154],
       [ 0.60856393],
       [ 1.6037076 ],
       [-1.37751807],
       [ 0.27298758],
       [ 1.74182634],
       [ 0.45654384],
       [ 1.63524933],
       [-0.93423304],
       [-2.03559187]]), array([[-0.11114176],
       [-1.92444931],
       [-3.65342767],
       [-0.78777011],
       [-2.12519832],
       [-0.08012127],
       [-1.61826407],
       [-1.28527636],
       [-2.07323325],
       [-2.96748178]])]]

and
newvalues:
[[array([[ 0.49047849, -0.49061768,  1.38129925, ...,  1.38365421,
        -2.84816588,  1.33435502],
       [ 0.14265502, -0.40701424, -0.06344381, ..., -0.04221331,
         1.87971909,  0.16228496],
       [ 1.25865165,  0.5694624 , -0.15033885, ..., -0.33268354,
         1.82849422, -0.32053569],
       ...,
       [-0.86875935, -1.31803218, -0.06188464, ...,  0.80358709,
        -1.22506318,  0.65488229],
       [ 0.72230337,  1.20813743,  0.70311973, ..., -1.31394859,
        -1.58026529,  1.573237  ],
       [ 0.75231614,  1.82261382,  0.28055294, ...,  0.63589566,
         1.54549887, -0.09006421]]), array([[ 9.04625312e-01, -1.20168740e+00, -2.05344286e+00,
         9.95282006e-01, -2.61128392e-01,  2.46883716e+00,
        -1.26605928e+00, -2.87461934e-01, -2.55345158e+00,
         3.95568507e+00,  6.47950996e-01,  2.92748875e-01,
        -1.90249337e+00, -2.05367861e+00,  1.17277862e+00,
         1.57364635e-01, -2.35467086e+00, -2.06776136e+00,
        -8.59204716e-02, -2.26256190e-01, -1.03518297e+00,
        -2.54459855e+00, -1.89909493e+00, -1.99529114e+00,
        -1.89778623e+00, -1.74062008e+00,  1.33135961e+00,
         1.66467987e-01,  3.65705086e-01,  1.15453112e+00],
       [ 5.18282670e-01,  2.10463982e+00,  2.22985297e-01,
         9.32875441e-02,  7.28948913e-01, -1.10041794e+00,
        -1.98894338e+00,  1.77096789e+00,  2.94633320e+00,
        -1.42998907e+00, -1.45059944e+00,  1.33818451e+00,
         2.37342106e+00, -2.77977954e+00, -2.89356946e+00,
         3.48555860e-01, -1.47593219e+00, -7.17198708e-01,
        -2.04548364e+00, -1.60860270e-02,  2.28442674e+00,
        -2.13940877e+00, -2.34960215e+00,  1.45710833e+00,
        -2.06243860e-02,  3.60329517e-01, -1.54618740e+00,
         2.19487096e+00, -1.04334123e-01, -2.94963266e+00],
       [-1.25268187e+00,  1.03468220e+00, -2.09360677e+00,
         2.72615924e+00,  8.03204286e-01, -1.21663915e+00,
        -3.14265961e+00, -2.99772834e-01, -6.55293117e-01,
        -1.85560311e+00, -1.69062463e-01,  1.53853932e-01,
         2.25068573e+00,  1.95227101e+00,  1.51207030e+00,
        -1.92508002e+00, -2.74164612e+00, -2.93852455e+00,
         2.01606172e+00, -6.91112599e-02, -2.27444607e+00,
        -2.75360145e+00, -1.62466484e-01,  1.68692850e+00,
         5.08041338e-01,  1.62613626e+00, -5.29857957e-02,
        -1.65836590e+00, -1.29237245e-03,  1.42649470e+00],
       [-1.00819993e+00,  2.63043465e+00, -8.48382777e-02,
        -4.38687260e-01,  3.76851240e-02,  5.60457581e-01,
        -1.86550332e+00, -4.34641085e-01, -3.02091630e+00,
        -1.55467958e+00,  7.91021890e-01,  1.23804246e+00,
         8.97229505e-01,  4.29841772e-01, -2.42525138e+00,
        -1.50064714e+00, -1.63826402e+00,  3.17469593e+00,
        -3.22054928e+00,  1.28392045e-01, -2.31741089e+00,
        -2.01552447e+00, -9.76992399e-01, -2.11558724e+00,
         1.92055199e+00,  5.55657968e-02, -1.75658363e+00,
        -2.46376324e+00,  1.73383489e+00,  1.56852876e+00],
       [-2.69408613e+00, -1.65159886e-01,  1.14444474e+00,
         1.23856668e+00,  1.02779879e+00,  2.81014023e+00,
         1.94193324e+00,  4.19896377e+00,  4.76766390e-01,
        -1.59098892e+00, -3.46217943e+00, -8.54517359e-01,
        -3.45234416e+00,  6.83242926e-01,  3.85724030e-02,
        -1.52278124e+00, -3.58015741e+00, -1.08273825e+00,
        -8.58495236e-02, -9.03825817e-01,  6.78730044e-01,
         5.18992143e-01,  3.42742226e+00, -1.52145368e+00,
         4.42189117e-01, -3.51066960e-01,  3.23080044e-01,
        -1.57079554e+00,  1.56477334e+00,  6.25506107e-01],
       [-3.33084155e-01, -2.79916035e+00,  5.22989199e-01,
         1.38178594e+00,  3.46671869e-01, -2.52869916e+00,
        -2.85003881e+00,  3.28334995e-01, -2.84497518e+00,
        -3.13336002e+00,  1.80758606e+00, -2.91602798e-01,
        -1.37399163e+00,  9.64047229e-01, -1.64202622e+00,
        -1.16234051e+00, -9.29535117e-01,  1.41014006e+00,
        -2.46834534e-01, -2.55373025e+00,  3.09016395e+00,
         1.98639570e+00,  1.10538587e+00,  4.80455892e-01,
        -1.63467864e+00,  7.28759567e-01,  2.64827251e+00,
         4.19659350e+00,  1.74234240e+00, -1.03982207e+00],
       [-1.99266677e+00, -3.45359895e+00, -1.66118838e+00,
        -6.86597421e-01, -3.64325347e-01,  2.37331770e+00,
         2.69295889e+00, -1.47113808e+00,  1.39082250e+00,
        -1.46233207e+00,  1.33042898e+00, -2.33113544e+00,
        -1.69593344e+00, -1.08305993e+00,  1.47304532e+00,
        -8.01031798e-01, -1.39920442e-01, -3.70400598e-01,
        -6.01091586e-01, -2.16153982e+00,  9.10587323e-01,
        -1.50354389e+00, -2.94728783e+00,  1.89153136e+00,
         1.43422568e+00, -6.14883762e-01, -1.29433499e+00,
         3.50730738e-01,  4.83855845e-03, -1.75349388e+00],
       [-1.65761588e+00, -5.63733247e-01,  4.25340960e-01,
         2.12352772e+00,  5.11942027e-01,  2.34213260e-01,
        -1.07488277e+00, -1.74688310e-01,  2.17174402e-02,
         2.48123976e-02, -3.62391678e-01,  6.56484593e-01,
         7.67530180e-01, -2.79774226e+00, -1.52769623e-01,
        -1.34026002e+00, -7.56261158e-01, -4.26031821e-01,
        -4.15734416e-01, -5.99522808e-01, -1.37719915e+00,
        -7.67536696e-01,  2.65846043e-01,  1.55756415e-01,
         6.99817419e-02,  5.52418194e-01, -3.16887735e+00,
         6.30433024e-01, -1.71636457e+00, -8.35886404e-01],
       [ 3.21696401e-01, -1.71443017e+00,  3.76632012e+00,
        -1.83856335e+00,  1.47475018e+00,  1.59866379e+00,
        -2.73854827e+00, -7.24335260e-02,  2.65913111e+00,
        -1.57314023e+00,  2.53103461e+00, -1.66971607e+00,
         9.40072925e-01,  9.69474126e-01, -1.69713625e+00,
        -9.04140008e-01, -2.44440263e+00, -5.97944024e-01,
         2.19066743e+00, -2.55224131e+00, -2.42208274e+00,
        -1.39494323e+00, -2.75270420e+00, -2.01258784e+00,
        -1.65333206e+00,  2.14839247e-01,  5.38008934e-01,
        -4.48039975e+00,  1.68560318e+00, -1.21934927e+00],
       [ 3.06599211e+00, -7.07372169e-01, -6.88577595e-01,
         6.59071311e-01, -2.00414045e+00,  4.02737209e+00,
         3.42991453e+00, -4.16059766e+00,  7.54238608e-03,
        -1.29674288e+00, -1.39663044e+00, -9.85410716e-01,
         3.45266027e+00,  1.56376928e-02,  5.27424947e-01,
        -2.58017367e+00, -2.34544641e+00,  8.51448321e-01,
        -6.64417574e-02, -3.17204624e+00, -1.60448330e+00,
         4.87718256e-01,  2.03572175e+00, -1.87365026e+00,
         3.12554540e-01, -1.03559520e+00,  2.60828651e-01,
        -1.13135153e+00,  1.25463236e+00, -1.43925684e+00]])], [array([[ 0.94832068],
       [-0.06266606],
       [-1.7593827 ],
       [-0.53870002],
       [-1.55386951],
       [-1.11558379],
       [ 0.02919313],
       [-0.28376287],
       [-0.54389668],
       [-2.50103053],
       [-0.08829055],
       [ 0.40428512],
       [-1.320014  ],
       [-0.59260049],
       [-0.77699536],
       [ 0.30419453],
       [ 0.33959821],
       [ 0.18065646],
       [ 0.55219802],
       [-0.02601865],
       [-0.01003154],
       [ 0.60856393],
       [ 1.6037076 ],
       [-1.37751807],
       [ 0.27298758],
       [ 1.74182634],
       [ 0.45654384],
       [ 1.63524933],
       [-0.93423304],
       [-2.03559187]]), array([[-0.11114176],
       [-1.92444931],
       [-3.65342767],
       [-0.78777011],
       [-2.12519832],
       [-0.08012127],
       [-1.61826407],
       [-1.28527636],
       [-2.07323325],
       [-2.96748178]])]]


Do you get the same error without all the pickle stuff and just myvalues == myvalues…? Because then pickling has nothing to do with it, and the problem is simply that your values are incomparable.

@deceze when I tried "myvalues == myvalues", it worked fine, but it was only when doing "newvalues == myvalues" that I got this error

Please post the full error traceback message.

@JohnGordon The full error message is now there

You've omitted the useful values of the print statements now…

@deceze that has now been added back in

"which is <class 'list'>" — Lists alone won't raise that error, it's one of the values in the list, so a [mre] there would help…

@deceze I have now added the values stored by both newvalues and myvalues, as was shown in the console when both were printed

This question is similar to: Comparing two NumPy arrays for equality, element-wise. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anerdw I have tried the answers on there- mainly (myvalues == newvalues).all() and  am still getting the same error, but when I tried np.array_equal(myvalues, newvalues), It tells me the array's aren't the same, but when pasted into a text comparer, it says they are the same. Do you know why it isn't comparing them to be equal in python?

Do a little debugging to figure out which values are giving you trouble exactly. My guess would be floating-point imprecision, but I don’t know.
